# Using custom trained Yolov3 weights to label new images

Tags: python, yolo, labeling, labelimg

I've recently trained a custom yolov3 model to recognize animals.
The first dataset only had around 900 photos. I have access to 10Ks of photos, but labeling them all through labelImg is going to take ages.

Is there a way to use the pre-trained weights to auto label new photos, with an option to then edit the boxes and tags if it is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can maybe predict on the other images using your trained model, see [this issue](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/issues/723).

Afterwards, these detections can be loaded into labelImg for editing.
Since darknet saves detections into a txt file with just bounding box info, you have to first convert these into Pascal VOC format.
You can do this yourself of course, but people have built [their own implementations](https://github.com/hai-h-nguyen/Yolo2Pascal-annotation-conversion) already (not tested).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a budget there are paid tools like [Segments AI](https://segments.ai/) and [V7's Darwin](https://www.v7labs.com/darwin) ,
both of which appear to have AI that assists with annotation. They learn from the items you have already annotated to automate future annotations. For the record I am affiliated with neither, and I have not used them.